# How to "rpm -i" a package only when an older version does not exist?

Tags: shell, shell-script, package-management, rpm

I wish to install some RPM packages from a shell script. I want to ensure that each package is indeed installed, but I do not want to update a package that would already have an older version installed (to avoid going to deep into dependency resolution).

How can I achieve this in such a way, that a case where an older version is already installed will return without an error code, while in other cases of failures there will be an error code returned? This so that I am able to control the good execution of the script.

Answer (score 7):

you can install depending of package existence in the system by:

```
 rpm -q mypackage || rpm -i mypackage.rpm
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command `rpm -q mypackage && rpm -i mypackage.rpm`. If querying for the rpm succeeds then installation of the rpm package will proceed. Else If the query fails then the installation will not proceed. However If you use `||` instead of `&&`, then despite of the previous command of querying the package fails, it will try to install the package, which anyway doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

What if you first test on whether the package in question is already installed and if not, you then install it. As you wrote you want to realize this within a Shell script, this would be some kind of `if`-clause.

Pseudo code:

```
if is_installed($package)
then
  return is_already_installed
else
  rpm -i $package
  return $?
fi
```

The first part could be extended by another test on the currently installed version (e.g. for a final report of the script).

Answer (score 0):

You may find `rpm -q <package name>` helpful, or even `rpm -U` for an upgrade.